# Control.Exception.Safe, why do ExceptT and Either behave so differently?

Tags: haskell, exception, error-handling, either

I'm trying to use `Control.Exception.Safe` with `Control.Monad.Except`.

```
throwString "Foo" :: Except String a
-- error, no instance for `MonadTrow Identity`
```

Ok, so apparently `Except` throws its error into its underlying monad in the transformer stack?
But why is that? Isn't `Except` basically designed to handle exceptions? Why this weird behavior? Why not the equivalent of `Left "Foo"`

EDIT:

Okay to further illustrate my problem:

I thought `ExceptT e m a` was to `Either e a` what `ReaderT a m b` is to `a -> b`. `Control.Monad.Except.throwError`, and `catchError` work exactly like `Control.Exception.Safe.throw`, and `catch` do with `Either e a`.
However they suddenly work different when applied to `Except e a`.

What do I do, when I want to use the behaviour of `Either e a` that is supplied by `Control.Exception.Safe` but in the context of monad transformers?

My context is that I do "Write yourself a Scheme in 48 hours" and wanted to generalize errors (with `MonadThrow`), so that I can do some IO stuff with it.

EDIT2:

Example:

```
data CountError = CountError deriving (Show, Except)

x :: String -> ExceptT CountError (Writer [String]) Int
x str = do { lift $ writer (length "str", return str); }
```

Now this count characters and collects the strings in the writer. This could be extended however much you want. The error could signal "wrong character in string", or "too many characters", or whatever.

```
y :: MonadThrow m => m a
y = throw CountError
```

This is a very general exception, which I could use for composition with any other kind of exception, except for `ExceptT`:

```
y >> x
-- No instance for MonadThrow Identity
-- But what I want is (Left CountError, [])
```

Comment: Except doesn't "throw it's error into the underlying monad", that's just what the MonadThrow instances is doing (N.B. `instance MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ExceptT e m)`).  If you want to throw an exception in the Except monad then you don't need `Control.Exception.Safe` at all, just use the functions in `Control.Monad.Except`.

Comment: Well I thought of `MonadThrow` (and the other typeclasses in Control.Exception.Safe) as generalizing `MonadError`, but that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: `MonadError` and the design goals of `MonadThrow` didn't appear in the question. Would you care to edit?

Answer (score 2):

> Ok, so apparently Except throws its error into its underlying monad in the transformer stack?

As I said in the comment: Except doesn't "throw it's error into the underlying monad", that's just what the MonadThrow instances is doing.

> But why is that?

The instance of MonadThrow can not throw a String exception into `ExceptT e` for all types `e` and rather than have an instance just for `ExceptT String` it appears the author lifted to throw an exception on the next higher monad.

> Isn't Except basically designed to handle exceptions?

Indeed `Except` is designed to allow for failure in exceptional cases.

Being pedantic, I'd call it an alternative to exceptions.  A monad plumbing an alternative notion of return (an error case) and calling itself "Except" doesn't actually mean any of the typical exception options, such as a low level stack unwinding, is in use.

> Why this weird behavior?

Because of the MonadThrow instance, which is re-exported from `Control.Monad.Throw`:

```
-- | Throws exceptions into the base monad.
instance MonadThrow m => MonadThrow (ExceptT e m) where
  throwM = lift . throwM
```

> Why not the equivalent of Left "Foo"

Because then the instance would have to be for `ExceptT String` instead of `ExceptT e`.  Or, that is why I think the author of `exceptions` (Edward Kmett) decided on this design.

Instead, consider using `Control.Monad.Except.throwError` which does what it sounds like you want.

> What do I do, when I want to use the behaviour of `Either e a` that is supplied by Control.Exception.Safe but in the context of monad transformers?

What "behavior of `Either e a` are you talking about?  How is what you are looking for different from `throwError`?  As far as I can tell, you are looking for an unnecessary extra layer of abstraction.

Comment: I don't see a question in your second edit and have no idea what you might be looking for in a response.

Comment: Oh, you want `MonadThrow m => m a` for a `m ~ ExceptT m2` with different semantics?  Well the semantics you don't like are already given for `ExceptT`. You can make a newtype such as `ExceptTWithString` and give a `MonadThrow` instance you like.  Aren't we just spinning around the same point that you don't like the existing `MonadThrow` instance?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of an old question but I think there is room to improve on this answer as I recently ran into this topic at work. Let's see, I believe that your expectation of having `ExceptT` behave similar to `Either` makes sense, but unfortunately the author of `MonadThrow` chose a different stance and decided that "passing" the decision on how to "throw" a failure to the underlying monad (or transformer) was the right way to go. Without attempting to speculate why decision was made, I agree that this behavior defeats the purpose of using a "failable" transformer such as 'MaybeT' or 'ExceptT' as an instance of an error class like `MonadThrow`, which is to give "Maybe" or "Either" like semantics to a different monad.

For this reason I have donned my flame vest and took a stab at `Control.Monad.Failable` , which would do exactly what you (and I) would expect, which is to return something like `Left e` where e is an instance of `Exception`.

[Control.Monad.Failable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/failable-0.1.0.3)